# Emberjs Catch-22 - parent computed properties that count hasMany related objects

Tags: javascript, api, ember.js, ember-data

Let's start with a common scenario where you have a computed property on a model:

models/coney.js

```
bunniesTotal: Ember.computed.alias('babyBunnies.length')
```

Lets say the entry point to the application is an index page showing all the `Coneys`:

```
routes/coneys/index
```

The API returns all the `Coneys` but it's paged, so only 50 appear per page (great, we don't want too many rabbits running around do we?)

Along with each Coney (parent rabbit) comes all of its children (since there are only a few of 'em, and they's only littl'uns - ie. small payload!)

So the `bunniesTotal` will always be accurate, and you can see it on each `Coney` in the list on the `coneys/index` page. Great, wonderful, a common example you see everywhere in Ember tutorials. **Ember goodness.**

Even more Ember goodness - after a user visits `/coneys/new.js` and adds a new `Coney` and some `BabyBunnies`, the user will see the above `bunniesTotal` update automatically when they come back to `/coneyes/index`, since the new BabyBunny is in the Ember <strike>Store</strike> Warren. Watership Down, come on!

Now let's travel to the future and scale our <strike>data</strike> warren. Uh oh.

Now the Coneys have thousands of children and maybe thousands of grandchildren too (yeah, Rabbits, go figure!)

It doesn't make sense now, on the `coneys/index` page, to load ALL the BabyBunnies for all 50 Coneys on that first hit. Not good.

So let's modify the API, and remove the `BabyBunnies`, so that each `Coney` must individually request them (eg. when you go to `coneys/edit` for example).

*But...what do you do about the count? Now the client doesn't know how many children each parent might have.*

You could include a property on each parent in the API instead of in Ember. So now you count the children on the server and send that total to Ember. Maybe a `meta.children_total` or just a property on the model. Ok, cool.

But now when a user adds a child on the client, the total is not updated automatically. You've lost that **Ember goodness** and your index page has now 'degraded' in the eyes of the user.

The user, after adding a new 'child' and getting redirected to `coneys/index`, will not see the total update. They will think something is wrong. What happened to the new <strike>baby rabbit</strike> child I just created?

**So, after that little time-travelling essay, here is the question.**

**Is there some Ember way to solve this Catch-22?**

Maybe a background refresh of the parent after adding a child to it. Or a way to just request the meta data for the parent, or some other Ember magic?

I had a look at [ds-references](http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/03/13/ember-data-2-4-released.html#toc_code-ds-references-code), and the [discussion](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/57) that happened on that feature, but neither helped me see what the recommended solution for this problem is/should be.

---

**UPDATE**

---

In that ds-references link there is this statement:

> retrieve server-provided metadata about a record or relationship

and this code:

```
var meta = post.hasMany('comments').meta();
console.log(`${commentIds.length} comments out of ${meta.total}`);
```

So that implies that the answer is to have a meta total on the BabyBunnies (children) provided by the server. `meta.total` would be a total of all the children.

But that leads to two further questions:

1. When the user adds a new Baby and saves it to the Store/Warren and
   hence the server, how does Ember get the new total? Does it do some
   background magic to just retrieve the total only? I suspect not, and
   that I must manually request the BabyBunnies endpoint just to get
   the new total.
2. What if that meta total is not actually a 'raw' total, but this:

   meta.totalFemaleBabyBunnies

   meta.totalMaleBabyBunnies

I don't see how Ember can update such totals without triggering a refresh of the BabyBunnies endpoint (which would mean doing that every time a new Baby is added!)

Have you had this problem? If so, what did you do to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the totals for the male/female baby bunnies directly to the active record serializer of the parent (ie. so they are properties in Ember on the parent model). Not separate meta totals and no need to use ds-references.

I just wanted to see if the most simple and direct solution would 'just work'.

So now when a new baby is posted to the API, the male/female counts are automagically recalculated and sent back to Ember as part of the parent payload. Boom, the counts update on the coney/index page, just like that!

Works like a charm.

I tested it with 1,500 `BabyBunnies` (using Postgres) on my local crappy five year old MacAir (Core i5 1.7GHz / 4GB Ram). Updating the two counts adds only about 1ms to the page load. So 1/300th of the blink of an eye :)

I will never have 1,500 `BabyBunnies`, so this solution is more than suitable.